# Component Wizard admin application does not starts in Oracle webcenter content

Tags: oracle11g, webcenter, oracle-ucm, stellent

Stand alone admin application componentWizard does not starts in Oracle webcenter content. Linux enviornment. Steps:
1) Path where the component wizard is.
cd CS_INSTALL_DIRECTORY/bin/

2) run the component wizard
./ComponentWizard

Result: No error but componentwizard do not starts

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I ran into something similar a long time ago.  Check your OS and Java Versions against the compatibilty matrix, chances are one of them doesn't match, the Oracle Certified versions.

Comment: Thanks, it was specific to OS & Java versions only

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a screenshot for the error ? The location to start it is :

/ucm/cs/bin

Comment: No error comes up. i checked the logs as well but nothing in there as well.sorry, its a very vague Q but this is all i have